# C++ 'Email' Does Not Name A Type

Tags: c++, class, qt-creator

I have the following class and when I try to compile I get an error stating that it is not a type.
What am I doing wrong?
Owner.h

```
#ifndef OWNER_H
#define OWNER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "email.h"
#include "phone.h"

using namespace std;

class Owner 
{
public:
Owner();
Email ownerEmails();
private:
int intID;
string strFirstName;
string strLastName;
string strAddress1;
string strAddress2;
string strCity;
string strState;
int intZip;
};

#endif // OWNER_H
```

Owner.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "owner.h"

using namespace std;

Owner::Owner()
{
}

Email Owner::ownerEmails()
{
Email e;
return e;
}
```

email.h

```
#ifndef EMAIL_H
#define EMAIL_H
#include "owner.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Email
{
public:
Email();
Email(int intID);
void setOwner(Owner o);
void setEmail(string email);
void setType(string type);
Owner getOwnerID();
private:
string getEmail();
string getType();
int intID;
Owner owner;
string strEmail;
string strType;
};

#endif // EMAIL_H
```

Comment: Show us `email.h`.

Comment: ZIP codes are strings, not integers.

Comment: And you dont' have to include `email.h` and `phone.h` in both header and source.

Comment: And also, if there is more to the error/warning log, show it in its entirety

Comment: There is lots wrong with this code, like the instance variables should be `private`, but that won't answer the question...

Comment: I added email.h sorry for the poor code I am very new too C++

Comment: You have a cyclic include dependency between `owner.h` and `email.h`. There are plenty of posts on that on SO.

Comment: Thanks I now understand why the error is happening just not how to fix it, but for the time being I can leave out the offending function until I understand more, and can fix it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#include "email.h"` and add a forward declaration of `class Email` before you declare `class Owner` in `owner.h`:

```
#ifndef OWNER_H
#define OWNER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "email.h"
#include "phone.h"

using namespace std;

// forward
class Email;

class Owner 
{
    ...
};

#endif // OWNER_H
```

Comment: When I forward the class it gives this error: return type 'class Email' is incomplete I understand that is because the compiler does not yet know what is in the class. Is there a way around this. I found the following, but have not been able to put it to use.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration

Comment: @Talon06 Yes, pass it back via a reference: `void ownerEmails(Email &email);`.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing based on the given information

- `Email` is nested in a namespace or other class/struct
- email.h is spelled wrong and you unintentionally overlooked the error that email.h could not be found (*perhaps Email.h*)
- The include guards are wrong (possibly OWNER_H in email.h)

Making no assumptions about your interpretation of the error messages ...

- Email is a template class
- There's a close-bracket missing somewhere in email.h
- There is no Email type defined anywhere in email.h or phone.h